# Python : strftime, when to use date lib, time lib, or datetime lib?

Tags: python

In [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) documentation , strftime appear 3 times. One implementation in "date" library, one in "datetime" library, and one in the "time" library.

All descriptions of this function refer to the same part of the page about the behavior of this function.

So when should we use time.strftime, date.strftime or datetime.strftime? Is their any difference in practice? Do we change only for clarity's sake.

Comment: have you read sec tion 8.1.8 it pretty much explains the differences and behaviour between the three [strftime-explained](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: They return different objects so what is difficult to understand from their usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will quote from the documentation.Refer the code to understand better.

**time.strftime(format)**

Return a string representing the **time**, controlled by an explicit format string. For a complete list of formatting .

```
>>> t = time(12, 10, 30, tzinfo=GMT1())
>>> t.strftime("%H:%M:%S %Z")
'12:10:30 Europe/Prague'
```

**datetime.strftime(format)**

Return a string representing the **date and time**, controlled by an explicit format string.

```
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("21/11/06 16:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
>>> dt.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")
'Tuesday, 21. November 2006 04:30PM'
```

**date.strftime(format)**

Return a string representing the **date**, controlled by an explicit format string. Format codes referring to hours, minutes or seconds will see 0 values.

```
>>> d = date.fromordinal(730920)
>>> d.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
'11/03/02'
>>> d.strftime("%A %d. %B %Y")
'Monday 11. March 2002'
```